# useing a variable in a another function inside a Class

Tags: python, class, variables

I want to use a variable in different function in a class.
Here is a simple code:

```
class Simple:
    def__init__(self):
       pass

    
    def func1(self)
        a = [1,2,3]

    def func2(self)
        b = a
        print(b)
```

How can ı use this "a" variable inside of func2 ?

Comment: You can make it an [instance variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables): `self.a = [1,2,3]` and `b = self.a`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451608/useing-a-variable-in-a-another-function-inside-a-class/71452291#comment126291791_71451608), you can make an instance variable.

```py
Class Simple:
    def__init__(self):
       pass
    
    def func1(self):
        self.a = [1,2,3]

    def func2(self);
        print(self.a)
```